# spark key find total elements in all tuples ignoring keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, key, tuples, pyspark

I have tuples like below. I want to count total number of elements. I know countByKey() gives number of elements by each key. I also know that  distinct().countByKey() gives distinct elements by key.

But I want answer 5 as there are total 5 elements.

Is there a quick way to do the same?

```
('http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets/11448761432933644608', ['spanish', 'vocabulary']), 
('http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets/8175198959985911471', ['topics', 'presents', 'museums'])
```

Comment: But the key isn't the same in all records

Comment: yes. the key is different. But i dont care about that. I just want the total sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is stored in an `RDD`, then you can just add two steps, a transformation and a reduction. In my following code I convert the tuple into just an integer using a `map` and after that I sum all the records using a [reduction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.reduce).

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([('http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets/11448761432933644608', ['spanish', 'vocabulary']), 
                      ('http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets/8175198959985911471', ['topics', 'presents', 'museums'])])
rdd.map(lambda x: len(x[1])).reduce(lambda x, y : x + y)
# returns 5
```

Comment: your solution works. Would it be possible to tell why `print (rdd.distinct().countByKey())` fails?